# Button print order does not show

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, magento-1, pdf

I have a Magento 1.9 and it does not show the button to print order pdf in orders. How I can enable this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK **the Print button is only available when viewing a shipment, an invoice or a credit memo out of the box in Magento 1.9.**

I suggest you follow this StackOverflow answer to add a Print button to your order view page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513085/order-view-page-print-pdf-button-magento

Comment: But in the grid not show the button. I don't see how print a order